# Create view from two tables with subtract operation

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by

I'm almost new with SQL syntax and I need help to create a view on MySQL.

I have a table with a PK column called `ID`, a column called `total_seats`  and another one is `title`.
In the second table, I have multiple rows, with a `firstname` column and a FK that corresponds to the PK (`total_seats`) present in the first table.

I need to create a view where I can calculate the `available_seats` (`total_seats` minus occurrence in the second table) for each element present in the first table.

Actually I'm calculating the "occupied" seats but the join give me the result only for already taken event, so the result is that I don't see the `available_seats` for the empty event.

```
SELECT b.ID_event, a.*,
COUNT(*) AS occupied FROM second_table b
LEFT JOIN first_table a ON b.ID_event = a.ID
GROUP BY ID_event
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subtract the count

```
select a.ID_event, a.total_seats, count(*) as occupied,  a.total_seats - count(*) difference
from first_table a 
left join second_table ba ON b.ID_event = a.ID
group by  a.ID_event, a.total_seats
```

Comment: It's works, but unfortunately seams it's counting ( and subtracts ) `ONE` 
 for the event ID with no match in the second table.
@scaisEdge

Comment: then update  your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ...

Comment: I've finally solve the problem, using this code to create my view.
Thanks to @scaisEdge for inspiration and first implementation.

`SELECT a.*, 
(Select COUNT(*) FROM second_table b Where b.ID_event = a.ID) AS occupied,
(Select a.total_seats-COUNT(*) FROM second_table b Where b.ID_event = a.ID) AS available_seats
FROM first_table a `